# Java Object Creation & Destruction

Tags: object

I've just now started learning Java and so far completed Class, Objects and Variables.
Here is my program,

```
class MyClass{
  int x = 10;
psvm(String[] args){
MyClass mcl1 = new MyClass(); //1st object;
MyClass mcl2 = new MyClass(); //2nd object;}
}
```

My Question,
-> Will the first object created out of the same class get destroyed once the second object is created?

Comment: No, it will not.  Both will remain valid until destroyed by your app

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's literally no limit to how many new and unique objects you can create.

Answer (score 0):

No the first will be not destroyed.
You can create a thousand instances of MyClass class.
Good continious learning.